# How to disable UI refresh on multiple click on BottomNavigationView item android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I've noticed that some apps use slightly different implementation when clicking on the `BottomNavigationView` menu item. By default, as I understand it, the user can click on the menu item many times in a row and then with each click the `fragment` will be updated

However, in some applications, clicking the same menu item multiple times will not update the `fragment`.

This raises the question of how to implement the second option so that when you repeatedly click on the same menu item, my `fragment` does not update and does not "blink"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just set the [setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView#setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener)) on your BottomNavigationView and let it do nothing.

Or [NavigationBarView.setOnItemReselectedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/navigation/NavigationBarView#setOnItemReselectedListener(com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationBarView.OnItemReselectedListener)) since the on above is marked as deprecated.